# Showing Two Polynomials Have Isomorphic Splitting Fields over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, cyclic-groups, splitting-field

Consider the polynomials, $f_1, f_2 \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$, given by

$$
\begin{align}
f_1 &= x^{2^n} + 1 \\
f_2 &= x^{2^{n+1}} - 1
\end{align}
$$

**How can we show that $f_1$ and $f_2$ have isomorphic splitting fields over $\mathbb{F}_p$?**

---

I think I have a bit of a messy way of showing this using the fact that we can write

$$
\begin{align}
f_2 &= x^{2^{n+1}} \\
&= (x^{2^n} + 1)(x^{2^{n-1}} + 1) + \cdots + (x^2 + 1)(x + 1)(x - 1)
\end{align}
$$

However, my idea seems quite inelegant and doesn't use the fact that we are working over a finite field, so I feel like I am missing something.

**Any ideas would be greatly appreciated**. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thinking about roots of unity looks promising...

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this hasn't much to do with the fact that we're working over a finite field. If you want, consider the question over an arbitrary field $K$. We may suppose $2 \neq 0$, or else there is nothing to prove. Call the corresponding splitting fields $L_1$ and $L_2$. Because $f_1$ divides $f_2$, there is a homomorphism $\phi : L_1 \to L_2$. To show that it is surjective, take a root $\alpha$ of $f_1$ of order $2^{n+1}$. Take any root $\beta$ of $f_2$. Then $\beta$ has order dividing $2^{n+1}$, so it is a power of $\phi(\alpha)$. Hence $\phi$ is surjective.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a bit dense here, but how do we know that $f_1$ has a root of order $2^{n+1}$? (And thanks for the answer btw!)

Comment: Never mind, I've got it! If $\omega$ is a primitive $2^{n+1}$-th root of unity, then (by definition) it has order $2^{n+1}$, and is also a root of $f_1$ (for example, this follows from the definition of a primitive root of unity and the factorization of $f_2$ given in the question).

Comment: Indeed. Alternatively, as $\omega^{2^{n+1}}=1$, we have that $(\omega^{2^n})^2=1$, so $\omega^{2^n} = \pm 1$. It can't be $1$, because $\omega$ has order $2^{n+1}$, so it must be $-1$.